# How to fix text alignment?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, errors, titles, text, titling

Update2:

Never mind, i made the mistake of including a extra \begin{center}. removing it fixed the problem.

Update on Thorbjørns solution

I did not manage to get it working.

When i include the pretitle, it works, but the sharelatex marks evrything in red like this [image]
I recive the following errors:

```
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\maketitle ...\@bspretitle \@title \@bsposttitle }
                                                   \maketitlehookb {\@bsprea...
l.48 \maketitle

I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.
 main.tex, line 48
LaTeX Error: \begin{center} on input line 48 ended by \end{titlepage}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...
```

.
    l.48 \maketitle

```
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
 main.tex, line 69
LaTeX Error: \begin{titlepage} on input line 48 ended by \end{document}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...
```

.
    l.69 \end{document}

```
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
 main.tex
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (52.16212pt): Make it at least 104.08003pt. We now make it that large for the rest of the document. This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.
```

Here is my updated code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
%packs
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[margin=1in,headsep=.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\pagestyle{fancy}


\date{\today}
\author{Peter Sloth Mierzwa, S154194  \qquad \qquad \qquad Jakob Will Iversen S143262}
\title{Kursusopgave 5, 62738 Digital signalbehandling E16 }

%headers and footers
\rhead{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{pics/DTUlogo.png}}
\lhead{Peter Sloth Mierzwa S154194, Jakob W. Iversen S143262}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{52.16212pt}

%
\pretitle{\begin{center}\Large}
\posttitle{%
  \begin{center}
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=6cm]{pics/UserPicture.png}
  \end{minipage}
  \qquad
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=6cm]{pics/UserPicture2.png}
  \end{minipage}
  \end{center}
}




\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\subsection{Digital to Analog}

This is correct

\subsubsection{Teori}
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering\includegraphics[width=7cm,height=7cm]{pics/DSP/DAC/R2R-schematic.png}
\caption{R2R diagram}%
\label{fig:R2R-diagram}
\end{figure}


Figur \ref{fig:R2R-diagram} This text is indented with the normal paragraph indent.
Make it long enough to wrap to the next line and you'll see that.

\subsection{test}
This is correct
\end{document}
```

EDIT:

I updated the question with a minimal edition

My code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
%packs
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[margin=1in,headsep=.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\pagestyle{fancy}


\date{\today}
\author{}
\title{Kursusopgave 5, 62738 Digital signalbehandling E16 }

%headers and footers
%\rhead{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{pics/DTUlogo.png}}
\lhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{52.16212pt}

%
\posttitle{%
  \begin{center}
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    %\includegraphics[width=6cm]{pics/UserPicture.png}
  \end{minipage}
  \qquad
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    %\includegraphics[width=6cm]{pics/UserPicture2.png}
  \end{minipage}
  \end{center}
}


\begin{document}

\maketitle
\clearpage

\subsection{Digital to Analog}

This is correct

\subsubsection{Teori}
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering\includegraphics[width=7cm,height=7cm]{pics/DSP/DAC/R2R-schematic.png}
\caption{R2R diagram}%
\label{fig:R2R-diagram}
\end{figure}


Figur \ref{fig:R2R-diagram} This text is wierd

\subsection{test}
This is correct
\end{document}
```

and it produces a result like this

[image]

**Original question**

I am writing my first assignment in LaTeX, but I encountered some problems.

I feel like I can't control the text alignment, if you look at the picture below, you will see that the text has a different margin than in the other sections.

Further more, if I choose to do a linebreak myself it makes some weird alignment too, as seen in the second picture.

I've included the code for the first picture at the end of the post.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%     DAC     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\clearpage

\subsection{Digital to Analog}

DAC'en skal omsætte et digitalt signal til et analogt signal. Her kommer et eksempel på et sådant kredsløb

\subsubsection{Teori}
\begin{figure}[!h]
\center{\includegraphics[width=7cm,height=7cm]{pics/DSP/DAC/R2R-schematic.png}}
\caption{R2R diagram}
\label{fig:R2R-diagram}
\end{figure}

Figur \ref{fig:R2R-diagram} viser et diagram over en 3-bit DAC opbygget efter R2R princippet.

Systemet giver en spænding mellem $0$ til $\sim5V$. For hver bit der bliver trukket høj, stiger 
spændingen.

MSB giver den største spænding (cirka $50\%$ af max), mens LSB giver den mindste spændings 
ændring. Udgangen svarer til summen af alle tændte bits.
```

EDIT:

Additionally i have 3 warnings in my document that might be playing a role.

```
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\maketitle ...\@bspretitle \@title \@bsposttitle }
                                                   \maketitlehookb {\@bsprea...
 l.52 \maketitle
                 I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and you
 forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases the way to
 recover is to insert both the forgotten and the deleted material,
 e.g., by typing `I$}'.


 LaTeX Error: \begin{center} on input line 52 ended by \end{titlepage}.
 See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H
 <return>  for immediate help.  ...
```

.

```
l.52 \maketitle
Your command was ignored. Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command, or  <return>  to continue without
it.



LaTeX Error: \begin{titlepage} on input line 52 ended by
 \end{document}. See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for
 explanation. Type  H <return>  for immediate help.  ..
```

.

```
l.110 \end{document}
Your command was ignored. Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command, or  <return>  to
continue without it.
```

Line 51-53 looks like this

```
 \begin{document} 
\maketitle 
\tableofcontents
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Replace `\center{\includegraphics[...]{...}}` by `\centering\includegraphics[...]{...}`.

Comment: To center content, you should either use `\begin{center} <some content> \end{center}`, or `\centering <some content>`. Since you're already in a `figure` environment, gernot's suggestion is the most appropriate.

Comment: Didn't fix the problem for me. I will update the question with additional info.

Comment: Providing a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)
 is the best way to help us help you !

Comment: There is something wrong (those are errors, not warnings, and should not be ignored), perhaps with whatever you have put in `\author`, `\title` and `\date`  (or other things that go into `\maketitle`). Try to make a complete, yet minimal example, as ebo asked for.

Comment: `Figur \ref{fig:R2R-diagram} This text is wierd` is indented because it's a new paragraph. You can see that if you input a longer text (2+ lines), the first line only is indented. You can avoid this by either typing `\noindent{}Figur \ref{fig:R2R-diagram} This text is wierd`.

Comment: Please do not update the question with answers, it makes understanding the archived site very hard to follow. Leave questions in the question and if necessary post a self-answer if posted answers do not answer the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that when you have a `\posttitle` you must have a `\pretitle` as well.

As ebo mentioned in a comment, the text isn't weird, it's just indented with the standard paragraph indentation. Paragraphs that start right after a section heading isn't indented by default. I would recommend keeping paragraph indentation. If you really don't want it, but instead prefer to have some vertical space to indicate the start of a new paragraph, add `\usepackage{parskip}`.

Also, you had loaded `amsmath` three times (`mathtools` loads `amsmath`), which isn't necessary.

Note that in the code below I added `[demo]` as an option to the `graphicx` package, as I don't have the images. You'll need to remove that.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
%packs
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[margin=1in,headsep=.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\pagestyle{fancy}


\author{}
\title{Kursusopgave 5, 62738 Digital signalbehandling E16 }

%headers and footers
%\rhead{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{pics/DTUlogo.png}}
\lhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{52.16212pt}

%
\pretitle{\begin{center}\Large}
\posttitle{%
  \par\medskip\begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=6cm]{pics/UserPicture.png}
  \end{minipage}
  \qquad
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=6cm]{pics/UserPicture2.png}
  \end{minipage}
  \end{center}
}


\begin{document}

\maketitle
\clearpage

\subsection{Digital to Analog}

This is correct

\subsubsection{Teori}
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering\includegraphics[width=7cm,height=7cm]{pics/DSP/DAC/R2R-schematic.png}
\caption{R2R diagram}%
\label{fig:R2R-diagram}
\end{figure}


Figur \ref{fig:R2R-diagram} This text is indented with the normal paragraph indent.
Make it long enough to wrap to the next line and you'll see that.

\subsection{test}
This is correct
\end{document}
```